How can I highlight TODO comment in rust file?
I'm creating a custom VS Code theme, and curious how I can highlight TODO in double slash comments in rust file. It works in .ts, .js, .go files.
I've added this to package.json
"grammars": [
  {
    "path": "./syntaxes/injection.json",
    "scopeName": "todo-comment.injection",
    "injectTo": [
      "source.js",
      "source.ts",
      "source.rust",
      "source.go"
    ]
  }
]

And how syntaxes/injection.json looks:
{
  "scopeName": "todo-comment.injection",
  "injectionSelector": "L:comment.line.double-slash",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "#todo-comment"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "todo-comment": {
      "match": "(?i:\\bTODO\\b)",
      "name": "comment.todo"
    }
  }
}

I think syntaxes/injection.json contains lots of redundant lines, if yes - would appreciate any suggestions.
upd(04-07):
New syntaxes/injection.json:
{
  "scopeName": "todo-comment.injection",
  "injectionSelector": "L:comment.line.double-slash",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "match": "(?i:\\bTODO\\b)",
      "name": "comment.todo"
    }
  ]
}


why do you need to use a repository, you only use todo-comment once so just add the props at the include place

does the rust grammar have the comment.line.double-slash selector

@rioV8 thanks nice catch with repository and include. In rust file its textmate scopes equal to comment.line.double-slash.rust source.rust
